# zsh: use setopt AUTO_MENU conditionally, depending on $PWD

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

generally, I find the zshoption `AUTO_MENU` annoying, and I disable it in my `.zshrc`:

```
setopt noautomenu
```

However, there are some directories where I have files with long filenames, with spaces in filenames, etc.

I would like to enable `AUTO_MENU` only for files in these directories (and their subdirectories)

How could I achieve this ?

Alternatively, I would like to use `AUTO_MENU` only when completing for specified commands, such as `mplayer`.

Comment: I think this is doable with `zstyle ':completion:SOMETING' menu SOMETHING`

Comment: @Gilles - could you please explain in more detail what I should put in place pf `SOMETHING` ?